# Provisioning profile not showing in drop down when distributing for Enterprise

Tags: ios, xcode, software-distribution

We created a new provisioning profile for distribution using the same team certificate as the former profile that worked, to extend the date. When I try to distribute for enterprise from archive, I'm only seeing the earlier dated profile. I'm not clear how to get the new profile to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the new profile to your computer and then drag and drop it onto the xcode app icon (in the system app tray). Then try to distribute it again through Organizer and you should see it.

Comment: I already tried that but for some reason the second time it worked, thank you!